# How can i slice an dictionary by key within json data in pyspark?

Tags: json, python-3.x, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

How can i slice an attribute within an attribute within json data?

Below I have posted an example snip of one business dataset from yelp which is imported into apache spark. I am aware as to how to take a slice of info based on an attribute so far. However how can i slice info of an attribute within an attribute. I have the following code below

```
rdd.filter(lambda x: x['attributes'].get('Alcohol')).take(5)
```

This code will return data that has the word 'Alcohol' within 'attributes'

However how can i take a slice of the data to show all attributes which contain 'alcohol' but also 'False' within that part?

I tried this code below posted from another user but this still shows whether it is true or false.

```
rdd.filter(lambda x: x['attributes'].get('Alcohol', False)).take(5)
```

I would expect the output to show all the businesses with 'Alcohol' in the 'attributes' and within that to have a 'False'

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

```
[{'business_id': 'vyutuvybuyb',
'attributes': {'Alcohol': False,
   'Music': {'dj': False,
      'background_music': True,
      'no_music': False,
      'karaoke': False,
      'live': False,
      'video': False,
      'jukebox': False},
   'RestaurantsGoodForGroups': True,
   'Caters': False,
'hours': {'Monday': '11:00-1:00',
   'Tuesday': '11:00-1:00',
   'Friday': '11:00-1:00',
   'Wednesday': '11:00-1:00',
   'Thursday': '11:00-1:00',
   'Sunday': '11:00-0:00',
   'Saturday': '11:00-2:00'}}]
```

Comment: check: `rdd.filter(lambda x: 'Alcohol' in x['attributes'] and x['attributes']['Alcohol'] is False).take(5)`

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It worked. I have been looking everywhere for a solution. Thanks again